# How can I create a looping fade-in/out image effect using CSS 3 transitions?

Tags: animation, css, css-transitions

I’m trying to create a looping fade in/out effect for an image. It’s working in Chrome, but it doesn’t work in Firefox.

Here’s the code: http://jsfiddle.net/FTLJA/254/

(I did make it work with jQuery but that made the browser slow and flickery on Android phones, so I’m trying CSS instead.)

Thanks for any help.

Update: fixed.. please check the link again

Comment: It what way does it not work? Works in Chrome 20 on my Mac.

Comment: yep! i'm testing on firefox fail but it work okey on chrome

Comment: i think you can reduce your example to `.objblink {
    -webkit-animation: blink 2s ease-in-out infinite; 
}`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, if ypu're only setting the WebKit properties (only `@-webkit-keyframes` and only `-webkit-animation-...`), then of course it will work only in WebKit and not in Firefox - add them with `-moz` prefix as well. Also remove the quotes around `'blink'` to leave it just... `blink` and it works http://jsfiddle.net/FTLJA/261/

Comment: Worth noting that in 2016 you don't need any of the vendor prefixes for keyframes and animation anymore. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes — this shows a difference between CSS transitions and CSS animations.

CSS animations run once you’ve applied `-webkit-animation-name` to an element, i.e. they can run entirely from CSS.

Transitions, on the other hand, only run when you change the CSS property that they apply to. You can either do this via CSS pseudo-classes like `:hover`, or via JavaScript.

So, in order to make your transition work in browsers that don’t support `-webkit-animation`, you’ll need to run some JavaScript that changes the opacity of the image once a second — `setInterval` is your friend here.

(Note that your JavaScript won’t carry out the animation, it’ll just switch `opacity` straight from 1 to 0 and back again every second. The CSS transition will animate this change for you.)

Comment: thanks for advice.. but as notice i dont want javascript so i just add some more to css: -moz-animation:blink 1s infinite; and create keyframe for -moz ...

Comment: @BinhNguyen: oh, of course, I’d forgotten `-moz-animation` is available too. Bear in mind that using `setInterval` to change opacity once a second shouldn’t reduce performance as much as doing the entire animation with JavaScript does.