# How do I make this fade in/out infinite?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this code fades in and fades out the div #shape while the start variable is true.
when i call the "start" method from event "click" the browser stops working because the while inside method is infinitive and "click" event does not finish until "start" method is done.
i want the method to run after the "click" event is finished.
what should i do?

CSS

```
#shape {
     background-color:red;
     width:100px;
     height:100px;
     display:none;
 }
```

HTML

```
 <div id="shape"></div>
    <button id="startButton">start game!</button>
```

JS

```
var start = false;
$("#startButon").click(function () {
    start = true;
    startGame();
});

function startGame() {
    while (start == true) {
        $("#shape").fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `while(start==true)` ? What is the click event? Do you mean the fading? You should look at how the jquery fadeIn/Out works http://api.jquery.com/fadein/ they both have a complete method

Comment: because i want it to fade in and fade out infinitivly

Comment: Should do it recursively then

Comment: could u explain more please?

Comment: I have added an answer with an example

Comment: This would be 10,000 times easier with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the flag, just make a recursive function. I changed the time to 300 milliseconds so you can see it easier

http://jsfiddle.net/zfbptz9c/

```
$("#startButton").click(function () {
    startGame();
});

function startGame() {
    $("#shape").fadeIn(300, function () {
        $("#shape").fadeOut(300, function () {
            startGame();
        });
    });
}
```

The div will fade in and on complete of the fade in, it will fade out then call the `startGame` function again and the entire process will repeat infinitely.

Alternatively, this can be achieved with css only if you only need to target modern browsers. I will put this fiddle link here, it is from a different question. I won't paste the code since you did not tag the question with css but the fiddle shows everything. I take no credit for it.

[How can I create a looping fade-in/out image effect using CSS 3 transitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578800/how-can-i-create-a-looping-fade-in-out-image-effect-using-css-3-transitions)

http://jsfiddle.net/FTLJA/261/

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript runs in a **single threaded** environment, meaning once you enter an infinite loop, you can only quit the loop from within it. In synchronous execution, like the one you have here, no code outside the loop can affect the loop condition.

As far as your problem, people suggested solutions such as making a recursive function or using CSS3 transitions.

Another possible way could be to use timing functions like [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) and/or [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval)

The code bellow will make the fadeIn/Out happen after every second, after start button is clicked and until stop button is clicked.

```js
var toggle = true;       // flag for animation direction
var shape = $("#shape"); // so we don't select the shape each time we animate
var duration = 1000;     // animation duration
var delay = 1000;        // delay between animations
var timerId;             // timer id returned by setInterval

// start animating the shape after the delay
$("#startButton").click(function() {
  timerId = setInterval(animate, delay);
});

// stop animating the shape and hide it
$("#stopButton").click(function() {
  clearInterval(timerId);
  shape.css('display', 'none');
});

// function that animates the shape depending on the toggle flag
function animate() {
  if (toggle) {
    shape.fadeIn(duration);
    toggle = false;
  } else {
    shape.fadeOut(duration);
    toggle = true;
  }
}
```

```css
#shape {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="shape"></div>
<button id="startButton">start game!</button>
<button id="stopButton">stop game!</button>
```